# Ansible API 2.3.2.0 tags passed to playbook but doesn't run task with tag

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am successfully passing the tag because the playbook is only running the task I have assign `tags: always`

The task that is assign the tag I am passing, doesn't run.

Three tasks for testing:

```
  - name: debug if tag was provided
    debug: var=tags
    tags: always

  - name: if tag restart was provided
    debug: var=tags
    tags: restart

  - name: if no tag was provided
    debug: var=tags
```

Only the first task runs when I pass 'restart' as the tag, all three tasks run when no tag is provided.  I want the middle guy to run when restart is provided.

Is there a way to see what the playbook is seeing as the tag?

The output for the debug is:

```
{
    "tags": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Here is how I am sending the tag via the api

```
Options = namedtuple('Options', ['connection',  'forks', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check',
                                 'listhosts', 'listtasks', 'listtags', 'syntax', 'module_path', 'diff', 'tags'])
options = Options(connection='ssh', forks=5, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False,
                  listhosts=False, listtasks=False, listtags=False, syntax=False, module_path="", diff=True, tags=_tag)

PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager,
                            loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)
```

**_tag** is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was I was passing the tag as a string and the API reads it as a list.  When I set the tag as a python set, it ran without issue

```
TASK = os.environ['TASK'].lower()
if TASK in authorized_tags:
    _tasks = 'none'
    _tag = {TASK}
    execute_playbook()
```

Answer (score 0):

`always` is a [special tag](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html).

> There is a special always tag that will always run a task, unless specifically skipped (`--skip-tags always`)

So use a different tag name for the first task if you don't want it to run if you specify the `restart` tag.

Comment: I use the always tag, to verify that a tag was successfully passed to the playbook.  When I pass 'restart' I expect that task with the always tag to run and the task with the restart tag, but only the always tag is working. I'm not sure how to see what tag the playbook is seeing when I pass 'restart' it seems like it is seeing something else.

Comment: The first and second tasks run when I run your playbook with the `restart` tag (using Ansible 2.4.0).  Maybe there's some other part of your playbook you're leaving out in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see what the playbook is seeing as the tag?

Since Ansible 2.5 (currently available as `devel` branch on GitHub) you can use a new [magic variable `ansible_run_tags`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md#minor-changes).

---

For example with `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --tags restart`:

```
TASK [debug if tag was provided] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_run_tags": [
        "restart"
    ]
}

TASK [if tag restart was provided] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_run_tags": [
        "restart"
    ]
}
```

When you do not provide tags for `ansible-playbook`, the value of this variable is `all`:

```
TASK [debug if tag was provided] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_run_tags": [
        "all"
    ]
}

TASK [if tag restart was provided] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_run_tags": [
        "all"
    ]
}

TASK [if no tag was provided] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_run_tags": [
        "all"
    ]
}
```